# Meta tag is not working in scrapy python

Tags: python, meta-tags, scrapy

I am working scrapy framework below is my spider.py code

```
class Example(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = {"http://www.example.com"}


start_urls = [
    "http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page1"
```

]

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    hrefs = hxs.select('//table[@class="knxa"]/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
    # href consists of all href tags and i am copying in to forwarding_hrefs by making them as a string 
    forwarding_hrefs = []
    for i in hrefs:
        forwarding_hrefs.append(i.encode('utf-8'))
    return Request('http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page2',
                    meta={'forwarding_hrefs': response.meta['forwarding_hrefs']},
                   callback=self.parseJob)    


def parseJob(self, response):
    print response,">>>>>>>>>>>"
```

**Result:**

```
2012-07-18 17:29:15+0530 [example] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page1> (referer: None)
2012-07-18 17:29:15+0530 [MemorialReqionalHospital] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page2>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1167, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 789, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 361, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 455, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 542, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/local/user/project/example/example/spiders/example_spider.py", line 36, in parse
        meta={'forwarding_hrefs': response.meta['forwarding_hrefs']},
    exceptions.KeyError: 'forwarding_hrefs'
```

What i am trying to do is i am collecting all the href tags from

```
http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page1
```

and placing in to `forward_hrefs` and calling this `forward_hrefs` in the next request(want to use this `forward_urls` list in the next method)

```
http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page2
```

I want to also add the href tags from page2 in the forward_urls and loop in this `forward_hrefs` and yield request of each  href tag, this is my idea but it is showing error as above, whats wrong in the above code, actually meta tag is meant to copy the items.
Can anyone please let me know this how to copy `forward_hrefs` list from `parse` method to `parseJob` method.

Finally my intension is to copy `forward_hrefs` list from `parse` method to `parseJob` method.

hope i explained well sorry if not please let me know....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried anything but it seems you have an error here:

```
 return Request('http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page2',
                meta={'forwarding_hrefs': response.meta['forwarding_hrefs']},
                callback=self.parseJob)
```

You are passing response.meta['forwarding_hrefs'] but it dosn't exist for this response

You need to put:

```
 return Request('http://www.example.com/servlet/av/search&SiteName=page2',
                meta={'forwarding_hrefs': forwarding_hrefs},
                callback=self.parseJob)
```

cause you have forwarding_hrefs field and this way you'll send it to parse job inside meta and then inside meta you'll be able to access response.meta['forwarding_hrefs'] cause it will exist in that response object.

Comment: yes ok that worked but how to access forward_hrefs list in parseJob method because if i type "print response.forward_hrefs" in parsejob method its showing an error exceptions.AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'forwarding_hrefs'

Comment: you access it like you tried to pass it in beginning: response.meta['forwarding_hrefs']

Comment: wow thank u that worked (if u dont mind) can we also copy item from parse method to parseJob method because we cant write two return in single method like return item return Request(url), becuase i am achievingpagination i want to save the data of first page in to item i want to use that item in the next page and add the second page data too for this item

Comment: of course you can , just do it the same way you did for forwarding_hrefs, just send another meta, let's say 'item': item and access it the same way in parsejob